# Gerrit notification for commits without any action

Tags: gerrit

In the Gerrit documentation there is no configuration setting, which could be used to automatically send emails **if there was no action** with a commit for a given period of time.

There is a notification type, **abandoned_changes**, but it means that the change was already abandoned.

What I want is an e-mail notification if the commit **was not abandoned, but there was no action with it**, like *Hey, do you really need this commit?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't configure Gerrit to send this type of notification but you can search for open changes which are not updated for a while like in the following example:

```
is:open AND age:1week
```

See more info about search operators [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-search.html#search-operators).

You can make a script (bash, perl, etc) to execute the query using REST and send the result by e-mail.

See more info about query changes using REST [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#list-changes).